# Insert value 1 in pandas Dataframe till one condition is met [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Dataframe with columns below minus the position column and my goal is to create a new column with name position that equals 1 when signal equals 1 and the Closeprice from the row that signals equals 1 is larger than the ATR. When Closeprice falls below the value of the ATR where Signals equal 1 the position will be equal to Zero.

[image]

Do you have any tips how I can do this?

Comment: Don't use image please. You can replace your image by the output of `print(df.head().to_string())`.

Comment: Hi @ErikBramme, I think that in your example, at the second line the `Position` should be 0 since the `Signal` 0. Am I right ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is my first thread so maybe I'm a bit confusing. I want the position in the second row to be 1 because Closeprice is smaller than ATR. Even though Signal is equal to zero. The signal column is only telling me when to "open" an position.

Comment: The position will be "Open" equal 1 till when the ATR from the row with signal = 1 is larger than the Closeprice for the active row. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `boolean mask`. Create masks for your 2 conditions:

```
import numpy as np

m1 = df['Signal'].eq(1) & df['Closeprice'].gt(df['ATR'])
m2 = m1.shift() & df['Closeprice'].gt(df['ATR'])

df['Position'] = np.where(m1|m2, 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Signal  Closeprice  ATR  Position
0       1          10    5         1  # True for m1 mask
1       0          20   15         1  # True for m2 mask
2       0          30   25         0
3       0          40   50         0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do it using the [`select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) method from `numpy` :

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> condlist = [(df['Signal'] == 1) & (df['Closeprice'] > df['ATR']), 
...             (df['Signal'] == 1) & (df['Closeprice'] < df['ATR'])]
>>> choicelist = [1, 0]            
>>> df['Position'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0)
>>> df
    Signal  Closeprice  ATR     Position
0   1       10           5      1
1   0       20          15      0
2   0       30          25      0
3   0       40          50      0
```

On the second line the `Position` is `0` since the `Signal` value is `0`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is my first thread so maybe I'm a bit confusing. I want the position in the second row to be 1 because Closeprice is smaller than ATR. Even though Signal is equal to zero. The signal column is only telling me when to "open" an position.

Comment: The position will be "Open" equal 1 till when the ATR from the row with signal = 1 is larger than the Closeprice for the active row.